# Errors when trying to clear Tkinter Entry Widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a project that will eventually simulate a filter for Twitter posts. I am trying to make a page in Tkinter that will allow the user to enter a Twitter account, and press a button that will add the string to a list and clear the entry field (have yet to code the append function). Code is as follows:

```
def Add():
            F.title('Twitter Filter: Add to Filter')
            def h_delete():
                        Entry.delete(h,first=0,last=END) # should clear entry, instead returns NoneType error
            for widget in F.winfo_children():
                        widget.destroy() # clears widgets of previous window
            global a1
            a1=tk.StringVar() # declares a variable that will be used to append a list with the text in the Entry
            h=tk.Entry(F,textvariable=a1).grid(row=1,column=1) # creates the entry I want cleared
            EntryButton=tk.Button(F,text='Add this account',command=h_delete).grid(row=2,column=1) # initiates the entry clearing function
            BackButton=tk.Button(F,text='Back to Home',command=Home).grid(row=3,column=1) # returns to home screen
```

However, when I run the code, I receive a NoneType error, as follows:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/skor8427/Desktop/Twitter Filter/TwitterFilter.py", line 22, in h_delete
    Entry.delete(h,first=0,last=END) # should clear entry, instead returns NoneType error
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2519, in delete
    self.tk.call(self._w, 'delete', first, last)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

I have read various help sections and nothing is working. Anyone have a solution?

Comment: Well, you assigned a value of None to `h`; the return value of `.grid()`, NOT the widget itself.  You need to do the creation/assignment and the geometry management as two separate statements.  Also note that method calls are more normally written as `h.delete(start, end)` rather than `Entry.delete(h, start, end)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
h = tk.Entry(F, textvariable=a1)
h.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

You have to grid h in other line else it will become NoneType
Try this snippet of code instead of

```
h = tk.Entry(F, textvariable=a1).grid(row=1, column=1)
```